# Окунуть в купель — этимологический плеоназм?

Tags: этимология, плеоназм

Является ли словосочетание *окунуть в купель* этимологическим плеоназмом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[окуну́ть](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-8783.htm)

1. Из *о-кѫпнѫти от кѫпати (см. купа́ть), подобно тону́ть из *topnǫti; см. Преобр. I, 645 (Фасмер).
2. -ну, -нёшь; прич. страд. прош. окунутый, -нут, -а, -о; сов., перех. (несов. окунать).
   **Погрузить в жидкость на некоторое (обычно короткое) время.** *Окунуть ребенка* (МАС).

[купе́ль](https://slovar.cc/rus/koler/1564024.html)
Бассейн или сосуд со святой водой, употребляемый для осуществления христианского таинства крещения...
Поначалу это были небольшие бассейны ок. 1 м глубиной со ступенями с двух сторон, по которым в них спускался крещаемый. Позднее получило распространение крещение через обливание, и в результате размеры купели уменьшались, а саму купель стали приподнимать над полом, помещая ее на особый постамент...
Существуют разные купели: большие каменные бассейны, устроенные неподалеку от входа в церковь, переносные купели для крещения обливанием и маленькие купели для крещения на дому (Кольер).

[купель](https://spiritual_culture.academic.ru/1124/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) — от ст.-слав. *купаться* (энциклопедический словарь педагога).

Да, этимологически получается, что слова родственны. Но сегодня значение слова "окунуть" не подразумевает процесса купания как такового (синонимы — обмакнуть, макнуть).
[Окунуть по пояс. Окунуть ложку в суп. Окунуть кожу в дубильную кислоту.
*Евдокия сердито окунула перо* (Толстой).]

Думаю, что современное значение словосочетания не содержит плеоназма.

*Когда разревевшегося младенца **окунули в купель**, мама испуганно выглянула из-за плеча подруги-крестной* ([окунуть.](https://books.google.ee/books?id=gSqLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=l2jr8gtq-5&sig=ACfU3U1GgjW5CsHemkcVUSx6mus3kQThCg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKxOmZyaXgAhWDhKYKHeoBBCsQ6AEwBHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&f=false) Новый объяснительный словарь синонимов русского языка).

*И вдругъ въ то самое время, какъ батюшка взялъ у кума младенца, чтобы троекратно **окунуть его въ купель**, въ часовню ворвался сильный ветеръ...* (журнал "Нива", 1903 г.)

Answer (score 1):

Это не плеоназм, потому что в этом выражении нет речевого излишества.

Comment: PS. Ответ был дан до редактирования вопроса.